# letters from Bern, Switzerland from the 1850's that i'd like translated

Tags: discussion

I have hand written letters from Bern Switzerland from the 1850's that I'd like translated from Swiss Deutsch to English. Is this the right site to ask for help with this? If not could someone point me to where I could?

Comment: No, that would be a "bulk proofreading/translation request". There are surely plenty of translators in Bern, which would do it for money.

Comment: Try it at https://www.reddit.com/r/Kurrent/